# Change variable integer on .click coupled with .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to alter a variable depending on the button clicked, and then update a div, all using AJAX in order to keep the page from refreshing.

index.php

```
    <div id="value1"></div>

    <div id="main-content">
      <?php include 'page1.php'; ?>
    </div>
```

page1.php

```
<script src="click.js"></script>

      <button id="button1">Load Page 2</button>
```

page2.php

```
<script src="click.js"></script>

      <button id="button2">Load Page 3</button>
```

click.js

```
var valueAdd = 15;
document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = valueAdd;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function(){
        valueAdd ++;
        $('#main-content').load('page2.php').hide().fadeIn('slow');

    $('#button2').click(function(){
        valueAdd ++;
        $('#main-content').load('page3.php').hide().fadeIn('slow');
})
```

So to follow the logic, index.php would load page1.php with the value of 15 within the "value1" div. Upon clicking the "Load Page 2" button, page2.php will load into the "main-content" div, while increasing the value in the "value1" div by 1.

It is not doing so, and I don't know the route to take to do so. All help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, is `workoutVal` supposed to be `valueAdd` in `document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = workoutVal;`?

There is no persistent link between your `valueAdd` variable and the innerHTML of the `value1` div.  When you initially assign the innerHTML value of `value1`, you are only assigning it the value of `value1` at that particular point in time.  You are not coupling the two together where a change in value in the variable will automatically propagate into a change in the div (this is however something that is commonly done in a lot of modern JavaScript frameworks, ie: AngularJS).

If you want your `value1` div to be updated when you click on your buttons, you'll have to explicitly do it in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function(){
        valueAdd++;
        document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = valueAdd;
        $('#main-content').load('page2.php').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#button2').click(function(){
        valueAdd++;
        document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = valueAdd;
        $('#main-content').load('page3.php').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/907o3eg4/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the variable. You are correct. I made the edit to reflect. Unfortunately, it is not changing the value displayed in the "value1" div when clicked after adding your suggested line of code. I then changed it as well to simply replace the value (valueAdd = 20;) and once clicked, it changed, but quickly went back to its original value (15). Thoughts?

Comment: @KyleHeier You were missing closing brackets and parenthesis in your callback functions.  Check the example I linked to at the bottom of the response

Comment: I appreciate your help @Lloyd Banks. Thanks a bunch